# PHP output multiple variable values if they exist

Tags: php, syntax

I have to output a list of multiple values. These values are not part of an array. I am doing it like this:

```
$value_1 = get_field('value_1');
$value_2 = get_field('value_2');
$value_3 = some_other_function('value_3');
$value_4 = another_function('value_4', 'one_more_param');

echo '<ul>';

if ($value_1) :
  echo '<li>' . $value_1 . '</li>';
endif;

if ($value_2) :
  echo '<li>' . $value_3 . '</li>';
endif;

if ($value_3) :
  echo '<li>' . $value_3 . '</li>';
endif;

if ($value_4) :
  echo '<li>' . $value_4 . '</li>';
endif;

echo '</ul>';
```

I have about 30 values. Is there a quicker, cleaner way to output this?

Comment: Put the values in and array and loop through them.

Comment: security improvement : `htmlentities($value_X)` instead of just `$value_X` when you output data in HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect your values to array and iterate over this array:

```
$values = [
    get_field('value_1'),
    get_field('value_2'),
    some_other_function('value_3'),
    another_function('value_4', 'one_more_param'),
];
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($values as $value) {
    if ($value) {
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Ha! I didn't see the if() in the loop. How did I miss that?

Comment: That is brilliant! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function to check if it needs display the item, then pass the value each time...

```
function displayListItem( $value ) {
    if ( $value )   {
        echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
    }
}
echo '<ul>';
displayListItem(get_field('value_1'));
displayListItem(get_field('value_2'));
displayListItem(some_other_function('value_3'));
displayListItem(another_function('value_4', 'one_more_param'));
echo '</ul>';
```